# If I put 'in order to' in this sentence, the meaning will be the same?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

original sentence [(source)](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=To%20use%20all%20the%20means%20within%20his%20reach%20to%20reduce%20the%20conseque):

> To use all the means within his **reach to** reduce the consequences of the incident

my version:

> To use all the means within his **reach in order to** reduce the consequences of the incident

- **IS IT THE SAME MEANING NOW?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It sounds a little more formal, but just the "to" form (often called the *Infinitive of Purpose*) is a bit simpler and easier to understand in a long sentence with many parts.